# Python Neo4j Driver and visualization

Tags: python, neo4j

I would like to get a JSON output from a Cypher query in 'Graph' format in order to pass based to the browser from my Python app to draw a nice graph.

However using the python driver I can't see a way to do this. In the API docs the rest driver has the ability to specify `resultDataContents":\["graph"\]}`[1](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/http-api/#rest-api-return-results-in-graph-format) but in the python driver there doesn't seem to any way to specify this.

Is there a way to get the python driver to directly output the JSON output?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to manipulate the neo4j query output using [COLLECT](https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-union-query-using-collect-clause/) clause.

```
Eg:MATCH(n:Person) RETURN COLLECT({name: n.name, age: n.age ,etc..}) as output
```

this query will have a json named output.

Hope this helps!